# Help to understand the usage of 'what' and 'but' in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Perhaps it was because he was now so busy, **what** with Quidditch practice three evenings a week on top of all his homework, **but** Harry could hardly believe it when he realized that he'd already been at Hogwarts two months.

I have 2 questions about the sentence:

1. I don't quite understand the usage of '**what**', because I feel it's fine to write: *Perhaps it was because he was now so busy with Quidditch practice three evenings a week on top of all his homework, ...*
2. I doubt the usage of '**but**', I think '**so**' seems make more sense to me. E.g.

> Perhaps it was because he was now so busy, what with Quidditch
>   practice three evenings a week on top of all his homework, **so**
>   Harry could hardly believe it when he realized that he'd already been
>   at Hogwarts two months.

P.S. The sentence is from Harry Potter.

Comment: **so** doesn't work. Perhaps there was a reasonable explanation for his distorted sense of the passage of time **but** Harry could hardly believe ...

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo is it like saying: although there seems to be a good reason (for Harry to believe it), he still could hardly believe ...?

Comment: Yes, *even though* he was able to explain how two months had elapsed in what seemed only the blink of an eye (the reason: he was so busy that he had lost track of the passage of time), *nonetheless* he could hardly believe that two months had elapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What** is mildly exclamatory there.

> He couldn't get to sleep, what with all the honking horns on the street ten storeys below. He was never going to stay in this hotel again.

Compare the following where "Why" and "what" are both used as mild exclamations:

> "Church has been nice and you could get home at a decent hour. **Why** lately everything  is in utter chaos and heaven only knows what time service will be over, **what** with all the blubbering going on."
>   -- *Heartbeat of Intercession* by Velma Goostree, 2009.

**but** is simply reversing the spin of the initial clause:

> Perhaps it was only to be expected that there would be traffic noise in the city, but he was never going to stay in that hotel again.

Comment: can all those words like *what, why, when, how, etc* be used this way?

Comment: Not all. Why, what, and how.

Comment: Can we take "what with" as a whole in this case? I looked up "what with" and it can mean "*Taking into consideration; because of*". It also seems to make sense to interpret it as: *he was now so busy, **because of** Quidditch practice three evenings a week on top of all his homework*.

Comment: @dan:    "With" alone means "taking into consideration, because of".  *With all the noise, he couldn't sleep.* "what"has been an interjection with exclamatory force in English for over 1500 years. In *What with all the noise, he couldn't sleep*  **what** adds some force to the statement.

Comment: Besides 'what' works with 'with', can it be used with other words to add mild exclamations?

Comment: @dan see the big OED under **what**, #21.  "Exclamatory and allied uses".

Comment: I haven't found the dictionary you said, but I found another one: *9. used in exclamations
What is often used in exclamations.
What a great idea!
What nonsense!*  Is this what you are referring to? This definition seems to be different and I'm already familiar with.

Comment: There are a variety of allied uses.